# Running docker shell on Windows

Tags: windows, bash, shell, docker

I've just installed Docker toolbox 1.9.1 (only docker itself plus Kitematic as I already have both VirtualBox and Git for Windows installed). Clicking on *Docker Quickstart Terminal* icon wasn't working so I had to associate it with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\bash.exe` as suggested. Now it starts fine but I'm unable to run `docker` command:

[image]

Kitematic works just fine but I need the shell. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check where `docker-machine.exe` has been installed (or [copy the latest released one in your `%PATH%`](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases)) and use that, instead of the quickstart.
From a regular CMD session:

```
# find the name of the machine created.
docker-machine ls
docker-machine env --shell cmd <nameOfTheMachine>
docker-machine ssh <nameOfTheMachine>
```

The shell you are after is the one provided by the Linux TinyCore `boot2docker.iso` image managed by VirtualBox, not the `git-bash` installed on your Windows host.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative option. Create the following `docker.cmd` batch:

```
cd "%ProgramFiles%\Docker Toolbox"

"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "%ProgramFiles%\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"
```

Now you need to start the `default` VM in your Oracle VirtualBox Manager (created automatically when you installed Docker for Windows):

[image]

and then the batch:

[image]